# Open new div below bootstrap col

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

Let's suppose I have the following table in bootstrap:

[image]

And I want to open a div with more information below the col when I click it:

[image]

Is this possible to do with css/javascript? I have tried the [Metro Dropdown](https://metroui.org.ua/dropdown.html) but the opened div is being constrained by the col-3 width. I have also tried to set the width for this div in css, but I can't seem to reach a result similar to the image attached.

What is the name of a behaviour like this? It seems like a "Dropdown" that push the bellow components a bit down. How do I do something like this?

Comment: The same way. Use `class="col-12 d-none"`. In the Javascript you remove the d-none class.

Comment: As far as I know the term "dropdown" is mostly associated with the `select` element, sub menu's and other behaviors that show a list of options. But it is not officially coined so you can call it whatever you want :). As for your question; you could do a couple of things. Add a `col-12` in the correct position, set the height of the `col-3` and position an absolute element in the created space or maybe experiment with CSS Grid? If you give one of these, or any of yourself, a try and get stuck then I'm sure that anyone here can help you out. But without code there is not much to do for us.

Comment: I'd call it a child row or detail row. Sure, you can do it. It's trivial with jQuery. What have you tried? SO requires that you make an effort and post your progress. At a bare minimum, post a simplified HTML snippet.

Comment: Also indicate whether you want to generate a new element, populate and show an existing one, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above, there are some missing specifications in your question. Here's a stab at it. If it's off the mark, update your question with more detail and leave a comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let counter = 1;

    $('.container-fluid').fadeIn();

    $('.col-12').click(function() {

        // slide up existing detail row with animation, then remove it
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.detail').slideUp(400, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        // create and append a new row with animation
        let detailEl = $('<div class="col-12 detail hidden">' + counter + '</div>');
        $(this).closest('.row').append(detailEl)
        detailEl.slideDown();

        counter++;
    });
});
```

```css
.row {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.col-12,
.detail {
    height: 30px;
    background: pink;
}

.detail {
    background: lightgreen;
    transition: background 1s;
}

.detail+.detail {
    background: darkgreen;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid hidden">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/o548b1Ln/)**